# Thread safety std::array

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a container e.g. std::array or std::vector, and I have 3 threads.
If each thread is modifying only one element

i.e.

```
std::array <int, 3> container{1, 2, 3};
```

thread 1 increments container[0]

thread 2 increments container[1]

thread 3 increments container[2]

According to the c++ standard:

Two threads of execution can update and access separate memory locations without interfering with each other.

That's mean that I don't need to synchronize between threads in this case (already safe)?

Comment: It is safe, however there will be huge performance penalty if those elements are updated frequently.

Comment: What's the best way to do so?